# How to convert one of my property of the JSON into an array?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

How to Convert my "Threat" into an array?

This is my JSON

```
[
    {
        "SensorType": "Visual",
        "Latitude": 1.3184418,
        "Longitude": 103.6282628,
        "Threat": [
            {
                "ThreatId": 56332,
                "Timestamp": "2018-05-02T13:15:43.6964862+08:00",
                "Latitude": 0,
                "Longitude": 0,
                "Bearing": 22.0,
                "FOV": 10.0,
                "ObjectId": "5320079"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is my Java file

```
public class Threat {
    //public boolean IsNewDetection;
    public String SystemId;
    public String SystemName;
    public String SensorType;
    public Double Latitude;
    public Double Longitude;
    public ThreatTimeDetail Threat = new ThreatTimeDetail();

    public class ThreatTimeDetail {
        public Integer ThreatId;
        public Date Timestamp;
        public Double Latitude;
        public Double Longitude;
        public Float Bearing;
        public Float FOV;
        public String ObjectId;
    }
    public transient Date Timestamp;
    public transient Date mTimestamp;
    public transient boolean isUpdated;
}
```

This is my Request Threat Java File

```
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
if (bufferedReader != null) {

    //not working
    Threat[] Sensorarray = new GsonBuilder()
                                .create()
                                .fromJson(bufferedReader, Threat[].class);
}
```

> The error state:Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 80 path $[0].Threat
>                      at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)

If I remove the [] after my "Threat :" from the JSON FILE, it is working fine.

Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is You are trying to Converter an array from Json:

```
[
  {
    ... ,
    "Threat": [ <<<<<<<<<<<<<
      {
        "ThreatId": 56332,
        "Timestamp": "2018-05-02T13:15:43.6964862+08:00",
        ... ,
        "ObjectId": "5320079"
      }
    ] <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  }
]
```

Into object:

```
public ThreatTimeDetail Threat = new ThreatTimeDetail();
```

---

**Solution is to create an Array instead of the simple object:**

```
public ThreatTimeDetail[] Threat = new ThreatTimeDetail[50];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Threat` field definition should be:

```
    public ThreatTimeDetail[] Threat;
```

Your json contains array data but you're mapping to single object instance hence the error raised.